# CesiumJS: Hayabusa 2 location w.r.t Earth

Tags: simulation, computing, hayabusa, 3d-modeling

Given these coordinates w.r.t Sun:

Hayabusa:

- x = 86014493
- y = 112689997
- z = 54295960

Earth:

- x = 82241037
- y = 112748971
- z = 48876281

How do I calculate Hayabusa coordinates w.r.t Earth center?

I tried with x = earth-hayabusa and x = hayabusa-earth, but it looks like it's wrong.

---

Here follows a method to visualize results of such calculation in a 3d viewer:

I have this JSON file containing the positions of some bodies w.r.t to Sun:

http://haya2now.jp/data/data.json

For example:

```
"hayabusa2":{"y":112689997.8606,"x":86014493.85948,"z":54295960.1354}
"earth":{"x":82241037.03488,"z":48876281.38811,"y":112748971.4809}
"ryugu":{"z":52629024.8754,"x":95901344.47932,"y":107641387.9349}
```

I also have data about location and orientation of antennas pointing Hayabusa 2 spacecraft:

```
"hayabusa2":
    {
        "alt":56.99,
        "azm":34.06,
    },
    "latitude":31.25,
    "longitude":131.08,
    "altitude":376,
    "sun":{"azm":254.6,"alt":-12.29},
    "name":"USC34"
```

So I am trying to create a 3d simulator showing position of hayabusa and arrows pointing from antennas to hayabusa; but something is going wrong, because arrows are not pointing to hayabusa position:

http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/3d/3dtracker.html

You can add Hayabusa object by running this code from console (F12 key):

```
// First attempt:
x1 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.x - obj.geometry[0].earth.x);
y1 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.y - obj.geometry[0].earth.y);
z1 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.z - obj.geometry[0].earth.z);

// Second attempt:
x2 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].earth.x - obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.x);
y2 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].earth.y - obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.y);
z2 = 1000*(obj.geometry[0].earth.z - obj.geometry[0].hayabusa2.z);

hayapos = new Cesium.Cartesian3(x1,y1,z1);
hayapos2 = new Cesium.Cartesian3(x2,y2,z2);
haya = {label: {  text: "Hayabusa 2",font: "24px Helvetica"} , description : "Descrizione", position: hayapos, point : {color: Cesium.Color.LIME, pixelSize:100},
  box: {
    dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
    material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    outline: true,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
  }
};

haya2 = {label: {  text: "Hayabusa 2xxxxxx",font: "24px Helvetica"} , description : "Descrizione", position: hayapos2, point : {color: Cesium.Color.LIME, pixelSize:100},
  box: {
    dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
    material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    outline: true,
    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
  }
};


hayaEntity = viewer.entities.add(haya);
hayaEntity2 = viewer.entities.add(haya2);

hayaEntity.name = "Hayabusa 2";
hayaEntity2.name = "Hayabusa 2aaaaaa";
```

Then use one of these lines to move camera to hayabusa:

```
viewer.camera.flyTo({destination:hayapos, complete: function () {viewer.camera.moveBackward(1000); viewer.camera.moveUp(100)}});

viewer.camera.flyTo({destination:hayapos2, complete: function () {viewer.camera.moveBackward(1000); viewer.camera.moveUp(100)}});
```

Note that Cesium uses meters as unit of measure.

I am trying with:

```
x1 = hayabusa2.x  - earth.x
```

and

```
x1 = earth.x - hayabusa2.x
```

Comment: The question is about how to calculate position of hayabusa in space w.r.t earth given its position w.r.t sun. Cesium is only an aid to view the result of such calculation.

Comment: `+1` Earth-to-Thing vector (i.e. position of thing with respect to Earth) = Sun_to_Thing - Sun_to_Earth which is your second choice at the top "x = hayabusa-earth" and first choice at the bottom `x1 = hayabusa2.x  - earth.x` That part seems right to me. If you have an epoch (the time for these vectors) we can check in Horizons in detail to see if there's something wrong or if your numbers are fine.

Comment: this is also my suspect; now I am trying to point to the sun at a given time to see if I can properly point it.

Comment: Not sure what precision you are aiming for but ephemerides and look-up of positions of the Sun, Earth etc should be calculated using TT/TDB which is (currently) 69.184s ahead of UTC. Also light travel time can be significant so positions at emitted time at the spacecraft vs received time at Earth can matter and for full accuracy, should be iterated. @uhoh unfortunately we can't; per JAXA request ephemerides for Hayabusa2 are not to be distributed and it has been removed from JPL Horizons.

Comment: @astrosnapper thanks for that, yep it was there [in 2016 as `-37`](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18851/12102) but not there now. http://haya2now.jp/en.html does not show barycentric coordinates and https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html probably won't either, so now the nature of this question and its relationship to antenna pointing directions makes more sense.

Comment: @astrosnapper oh rats! If there were no further answers when the bounty expires on [How far did Hayabusa-2 back off before the “bomb” went off?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35307/12102) I was going to answer myself using Horizons, now I can't, grrr... I can't understand the current answer sufficiently to know if it's correct or not.

Comment: I monitored for months past and future ephemeris of hayabusa by my page ( http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/3d/space-explorer-tracker.html?orbiter=-37&center=@399&start=2020-12-5%2016:30&stop=2020-12-5%2018:30&step=1m&3dzoom=20000&radius=6300 )  , which used NASA Horizons data for "-37" id, but the id was suddenly removed from Horizons a couple of days ago; it had been added in 2015, see news here: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons_news   But... http://win98.altervista.org/hayabusa2/hayabusa2-tracker.html?xaxis=4&yaxis1=30&yaxis2=33&separator=\t&first=7750&yzoom=50000000

Comment: Copy full link from http to 5000000, use Chrome:  "http://win98.altervista.org/hayabusa2/hayabusa2-tracker.html?xaxis=4&yaxis1=30&yaxis2=33&separator=\t&first=7750&yzoom=50000000"

Comment: Anyway Horizons never provided precise location of H2 around Ryugu: the minimum available precision for so far objects is around 300km, but H2 operated below 20km; this is why H2 carries a LIDAR for low-altitude operations. I remember same issue for Rosetta around 67P: it was not possible to locate it with precision greater than 200 km.

Comment: Trajectory plan from JAXA site: https://www.hayabusa2.jaxa.jp/hy2sc4/data/hy2_trj_plan.txt